# Взаимодействие между двумя окнами и изменение контента кнопки WPF MVVM C#

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, mvvm, шаблоны-проектирования

Есть два окна (MainWindow и SecondWindow). На MainWindow экране расположена кнопка. Нажав на нее нужно открыть окно и изменить запись со "Старт" на "Стоп". После закрытия снова изменить контент кнопки на "Старт". Делаю на MVVM + реализация интерфейса IСommand. Сейчас у меня выходит запустить второе окно и изменить текст, но при закрытии окна не знаю, как снова надпись на кнопке изменить и при нажатии можно сколь угодно окон открыть. А мне нужно что бы открывалось окно один раз, пока не закроем, вызывать его запрещено. Прошу помощи уважаемые программисты.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<Window x:Class="CommandMVVM.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CommandMVVM"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Window.Resources>
    <local:MainWindowViewModel x:Key="MainWindowViewModel" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource MainWindowViewModel}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Button Name="v_Button_ToggleNextWindow" Grid.Row="1" Command="{Binding StartStopCommand, Mode=OneTime}"  
            VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="90">
        <Button.Content>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ButtonContent}" />
        </Button.Content>
    </Button>

</Grid>
```

Класс ВьюМодели

```
 public class MainWindowViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    SecondWindow rg; 

    /// <summary>
    /// Комманда для кнопки открывающей второе вью
    /// </summary>
    //private ICommand _toggleSecondViewCommand;
    //public ICommand ToggleSecondViewCommand
    //{
    //    get
    //    {
    //        return _toggleSecondViewCommand;
    //    }

    //    private set { }
    //}

    /// <summary>
    /// Надпись на кнопке
    /// </summary>
    private string _buttonContent;
    public string ButtonContent
    {
        get => _buttonContent;
        set
        {
            _buttonContent = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ButtonContent");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Флаг 
    /// </summary>
    private bool _IsRunning;
    public bool IsRunning
    {
        get => _IsRunning;
        set
        {
            _IsRunning = value;
            //обновление кнопки
            StartStopCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Кнопка запуска и останова
    /// </summary>
    private RelayCommand _StartStopCommand;
    public RelayCommand StartStopCommand
    {
        // get {return }
        get => _StartStopCommand = _StartStopCommand ?? new RelayCommand(ToggleSecondViewExecute, CanStartStop);
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///.ctor 
    /// </summary>
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        //InitializeCommands();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Start/Stop flag
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private bool CanStartStop()
    {
        if (IsRunning)
        {
            ButtonContent = "Стоп";
        }
        else
        {
            ButtonContent = "Старт";
        }

        return true;
    }


    private void ToggleSecondViewExecute()
    {
        Boolean windowOpened = false;

        if (IsRunning && rg != null)
        {
            IsRunning = false;
        }

        else
        {
            if (!windowOpened)
            {

                windowOpened = true;
                IsRunning = true;
                rg = new SecondWindow();
                rg.Show();
                Debug.WriteLine($"IsRunning = {IsRunning} ButtonContent = {ButtonContent}");
            }
         }
    }

    // Deprecated
    //private void InitializeCommands()
    //{
    //    _toggleSecondViewCommand = new RelayCommand(ToggleSecondViewExecute);
    //}
}
```

Класс Команды

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    Action _targetExecuteMethod;
    Func<bool> _targetCanExecuteMethod;

    public RelayCommand(Action executeMethod)
    {
        _targetExecuteMethod = executeMethod;
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action executeMethod, Func<bool> canExecuteMethod)
    {
        _targetExecuteMethod = executeMethod;
        _targetCanExecuteMethod = canExecuteMethod;
    }

    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        CanExecuteChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
    #region ICommand Members

    bool ICommand.CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        if (_targetCanExecuteMethod != null)
        {
            return _targetCanExecuteMethod();
        }
        if (_targetExecuteMethod != null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    // Beware - should use weak references if command instance lifetime is longer than lifetime
    // of UI objects that get hooked up to command
    // Prism commands solve this in their implementation
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged = delegate { };

    void ICommand.Execute(object parameter)
    {
        if (_targetExecuteMethod != null)
        {
            _targetExecuteMethod();
        }
    }
    #endregion
}

public class RelayCommand<T> : ICommand
{
    Action<T> _targetExecuteMethod;
    Func<T, bool> _targetCanExecuteMethod;

    public RelayCommand(Action<T> executeMethod)
    {
        _targetExecuteMethod = executeMethod;
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<T> executeMethod, Func<T, bool> canExecuteMethod)
    {
        _targetExecuteMethod = executeMethod;
        _targetCanExecuteMethod = canExecuteMethod;
    }

    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        CanExecuteChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
    #region ICommand Members

    bool ICommand.CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        if (_targetCanExecuteMethod != null)
        {
            T tparm = (T)parameter;
            return _targetCanExecuteMethod(tparm);
        }
        if (_targetExecuteMethod != null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    // Beware - should use weak references if command instance lifetime is longer than lifetime of 
    // UI objects that get hooked up to command
    // Prism commands solve this in their implementation
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged = delegate { };

    void ICommand.Execute(object parameter)
    {
        if (_targetExecuteMethod != null)
        {
            _targetExecuteMethod((T)parameter);
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Класс оповещения

```
public abstract class NotificationObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected void SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value))
        {
            field = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        }
    }
}
```

Базовый класс для ВьюМодели

```
 public class BaseViewModel : NotificationObject
{

}
```

Comment: Решение напрашивается само: если `rg !=null` значит нужно окно закрыть и поменять надпись на кнопке на "Старт". Это все можно сделать в том же методе `ToggleSecondViewExecute()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я бы сделал что то на подобие такого:

### Xaml разметка

Тут я создал простейшую кнопку, у которой указаны DataTriger. Если `IsRunning=true`, то пишем "Стоп" и к примеру делаем ее неактивной. При false наоборот. Ну и привязались к команде, да.

```
<Button Width="60" Height="30" Command="{Binding SimpleCommand}">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <!-- Triggered values -->
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Test.IsRunning}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="Стоп"/>
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Test.IsRunning}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="Старт"/>
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

### Код

- VM - Тут все простенько, реализуем INotifyPropertyChanged с той самой IsRunning.

  ```
  public class TestViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
      private bool _isRunning;
      public bool IsRunning
      {
          get => _isRunning;
          set
          {
              _isRunning = value;
              OnPropertyChanged();
          }
      }

      public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

      protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
      {
          PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
      }
  }
  ```
- Ну и привязка (я это сделал прям в MainWindow):

  ```
  public TestViewModel Test { get; set; } = new TestViewModel();

  public MainWindow()
  {
      InitializeComponent();
      SimpleCommand = new RelayCommand(DoSimpleCommand);
      DataContext = this;
  }
  ```
- Осталась команда и с этим окном покончили. Тут уже в ход идет ваша фантазия (я лично не знаю что вы там останавливать собрались, по этому просто открываем окно, если его еще нет):

  ```
  private SecondWindow rg;
  private void DoSimpleCommand()
  {
      Test.IsRunning = true;
      if (rg == null || rg.IsClosed)
      {
          rg = new SecondWindow(Test);
      }

      rg.Show();
  }

  public RelayCommand SimpleCommand { get; }
  ```
- Ну и немного переделаем второе окно. Нам надо в него передать ссылку на нашу VM и менять ее при закрытие окна. Также хотелось бы знать, то окно закрылось, по этому перепишем немного OnClosed. Весь код второго окна будет примерно следующий:

  ```
  private TestViewModel Test { get; }

  public SecondWindow(TestViewModel test)
  {
      InitializeComponent();
      Test = test;
  }

  public bool IsClosed { get; private set; }
  protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
  {
      base.OnClosed(e);
      Test.IsRunning = false;
      IsClosed = true;
  }
  ```

Вот и все. При нажатие на кнопку у нас откроется окно, текст на кнопке поменяется и кнопка станет не активной. При закрытие окна, все произойдет наоборот.

[image: result]

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Скажите, а то что мы контент меняем через разметку не противоречит подходу использования MVVM и ICommand? И еще, INotifyPropertyChanged у меня реализован в отдельном классе и там же есть событие и SetField<T>, мне получается просто нужно будет отнаследоваться от этого класса и передать в NotifyPropertyChanged [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null ?

Comment: @JDo Ну смотрите... MVVM - его суть заключается в разделение всего на 3 слоя. View - слой, который отвечает за дизайн. Другие слои по задумке MVVM не должны знать об элементах во View слое. Так почему бы нам все это не сделать через XAML разметку? Это же View и код не знает... По этому я думаю, что тут нечего не противоречит. К тому же Старт/Стоп это число элемент дизайна и в коде (даже в коде view слоя) нам это не как не понадобится. Что касается INPC - мне просто было лень копировать то, что у вас, легче было нажать в студии "реализовать интерфейс", по этому спокойно можете использовать свой

Comment: Спасибо! Жму вам руку!