# Как привязать цвет эллипса к полю объекта?

Tags: c#, wpf

Пытаюсь привязать цвет эллипса к полю созданного класса, но ничего не выходит. Что я делаю не так? Xaml:

```
    <Ellipse Width="5" Height="5" x:Name="Ell" Fill="{Binding elipce}" Grid.Column="0"/>
```

C#:

```
    elipce = new SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Colors.Green);
```

Comment: На сколько я знаю, к полям привязка не работает. Используйте свойства!

Comment: @EvgeniyZ привязка текста лэйбла к текстовому полю прекрасно работает

Comment: Будет интересно увидеть данную привязку...

Comment: А какого типа свойство ваше?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ `<Label x:Name="NameLabel" Content="{Binding Path=name}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="0" Foreground="White"/>`
@АндрейNOP Brush

Comment: А в коде как name задается?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ В коде это обычное поле обычного класса, объект которого добавляется к списку, элементом которого служит этот объект `public string name { get; set; }`

Comment: Так, давайте разберемся. `public string name;` - это **поле** (field), привязать к полю **не возможно**! `public string name {get; set;}` - это свойство (property) и к нему идет вся привязка.

Comment: Теперь что касается вопроса, что мешает создать свойство, к примеру `public Brush Color {get; set;}` и к нему привязаться? В чем ваша проблема?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ прошу прощения, перепутал. У меня создано это свойство с цветом, Который меняется в конструкторе.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Вот [код класса](https://pastebin.com/JELqQNUW)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так, что бы не тянуть у вас сотню раз миллион строк кода, напишу простенький ответ...
В комментариях мы уже разобрались надеюсь с вами со свойствами и полями.

### Напомню

- `public string Name;` - это **поле** (Field). Если вы привяжитесь к нему, то будете получать ошибку о том, что "Свойство Name не найдено".
- `public string Name {get; set;}` - это **свойство** (Property), они как раз и используются для работы с привязками (Binding).

### По вашей проблеме

> У меня создано это свойство с цветом, Который меняется в конструкторе.

- Если оно создано, к нему успешно все привязалось (нет в логах ошибок), то скорей всего у вас не реализован *INotifyPropertyChanged*.
- Если оно создано, но не привязывается, то либо у вас оно не имеет `public` доступа, либо что то не так с get.

### Пример

Покажу простой до безобразия пример того, что вы хотите (буду писать топорно, на практике лучше реализовывать команды и все, что связано с MVVM (view, viewmodel и model).

#### Разметка XAML

- Значит, создадим простую разметку, которая будет содержать 3 button и ellipse:

  ```
  <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition/>
          <RowDefinition/>
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <Ellipse Grid.Row="0" Width="30" Height="30" Fill="{Binding Color}" Margin="0,0,0,5"/>
      <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
          <Button Click="BtnClick" Name="RedBtn" Width="60" Height="30" Content="Красный"/>
          <Button Click="BtnClick" Name="BlueBtn" Width="60" Height="30" Content="Синий"/>
          <Button Click="BtnClick" Name="GreenBtn" Width="60" Height="30" Content="Зеленый"/>
      </StackPanel>
  </Grid>
  ```
- Как видим тут уже я указал привязку цвета к некому `Color`, так давайте  его создадим, но.. Для начала реализуем INPC (INotifyPropertyChanged):

#### INotifyPropertyChanged

Что такое INotifyPropertyChanged? По сути это некий инструментарий, который помогает нам взаимодействовать с холстом (то есть окном и его View частью). Другими словами, с помощью данного интерфейса мы оповещаем нашу View об изменениях, которые произошли с нашими свойствами, что в итоге обновляет привязанные контролы (меняет текст, цвет, размер и др.).

Для реализации нам понадобится (есть кстати очень хороший вариант, который расписан в [этом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/632517/%D0%93%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0/632894#632894) ответе:

- У нашего класса со свойствами смотрим, могут ли они изменится и нужно ли нам обновлять ради них интерфейс, если такие свойства есть, то после названия класса пишем (через двоеточие) `: INotifyPropertyChanged`.
- Далее хоть убейте, но до сих пор не знаю кто это предлагает, ReSharper или сама студия, но у меня при наведение на подчеркивающуюся надпись высвечивается помощник, который предлагает реализовать недостающие строчки кода (скорей всего ReSharper), так вот, создается следующий код в нашем классе:

  ```
  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
  {
      PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }
  ```
- Все, наша VM готова для оповещения наших контролов об изменение данных.

#### Создание свойства

Как мы уже разобрались выше - привязывается WPF любит именно к свойствам, так давайте его создадим:

- Но, здесь нам надо еще сказать, что "данное свойство изменилось" и для этого создается вот такое "чудо":

  ```
  private Brush color;
  public Brush Color
  {
      get => color;
      set
      {
          color = value;
          OnPropertyChanged();
      }
  }
  ```

Что тут происходит? Смотрите, при получение данных (get) - мы отдаем значение, которое хранится в приватной переменной, а при изменение данных (set) - мы нашей приватной переменной задает измененное значение и вызываем `OnPropertyChanged();`, который оповестит интерфейс о новом значение. Такое свойство вам надо будет делать везде, где надо оповестить интерфейс об изменение.

Весь код нашей VM:

```
public class TestViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Brush color;
    public Brush Color
    {
        get => color;
        set
        {
            color = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Все, тут я думаю уже ваша проблема будет решена.

#### Допишем приложение...

- В главном окне укажем нашу VM, как свойство:

  ```
  private TestViewModel TestVM { get; set; } = new TestViewModel();
  ```
- В конструкторе MainWindow укажем DataContext:

  ```
  DataContext = TestVM;
  ```
- Ну и на последок, топорно будем менять цвет в нашей VM (лень было делать команду, а надо...):

  ```
  private void BtnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
      var btn = sender as Button;
      switch (btn?.Name)
      {
          case "RedBtn":
              TestVM.Color = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
              break;
          case "GreenBtn":
              TestVM.Color = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
              break;
          case "BlueBtn":
              TestVM.Color = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
              break;
      }
  }
  ```
- Запускаем и... Результат:

[image: result]

Comment: Это хороший ответ на мой вопрос, но я заметил одну интересную вещь. Если оставить [вот так](https://pastebin.com/JELqQNUW), и вызывать метод, который добавляет объект из главного потока, то все будет хорошо, кружочки в списке будут меняться в зависимости от вошедшего `status`, но дело в том, что мне нужно вызывать добавление из другого потока, добавляю новый объект [вот так](https://pastebin.com/qZmzVcGg). Но в этом случае, после получения всех `User`, я получаю [это](https://sun9-3.userapi.com/c840621/v840621862/7a74f/a..). Совсем не понимаю что не так.

Comment: А самое интересное, что если я закомменчу кусок кода, который в зависимости от `status` меняет цвет свойства `elipce`, то все хорошо, все запускается, но уже, понятное дело, без кружочков.

Comment: @ElRabbito Скрин с первого комментария не рабочий, не знаю в чем у вас проблема. А что касается статуса, его как по мне лучше вовсе во View перенести (как к примеру [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/818455/220553)

Comment: [Перезалил в другое место](https://ibb.co/icqzUH)

Comment: Больше всего меня удивляет, что текст, почему-то, нормально биндится так, как я делаю, а вот эти кружочки - нет.
[Вот результат](https://ibb.co/mxqV3c) добавления элементов например сразу после [инициализации](https://pastebin.com/vGXQQQ3U). Если добавлять из другого потока с помощью `Dispatcher`, то при незакоменченном цвете в конструкторе объекта `User` приложение переходит в режим приостановки выполнения. Почему именно на этом свойстве свет клином не сошелся я не знаю. Загадка какая-то.

Comment: @ElRabbito То, что у вас на скрине (ошибка) - обычно такое бывает в проблеме с разметкой XAML. А что касается элементов, то я не могу нечего сказать без кода. Я вам дал уже пример того, как сделал бы я это все...

Comment: Я попробовал сделать, как предложили вы, но единственное, что поменялось это то, что приложение больше не переходит в режим приостановки выполнения. Кружки все равно не появляются

Comment: @ElRabbito Ну смотрите ошибки привязки. Повторюсь, я не могу без кода и без разметки что либо сказать. Вы мне дали всего лишь пустую модель. Кстати, которая не реализует еще и INPC (что указано в ответе...)

Comment: Честно говоря, не понимаю о каких ошибках привязки идет речь, если я привел пример когда все работает, но это для случая, когда добавление в список вызывается из главного потока, но у меня такая задача, что вызывать это нужно из другого потока, в котором, почему-то, именно эллипс не работает

Comment: Проблема оказалось в том, что метод нужно было вызывать через `Invoke`, а не через `BeginInvoke`